# Listing image files in a directory in the order that they are displayed in

Tags: python, file

I am working on an semantic segmentation task using the MHP dataset. I've downloaded the dataset and it has the following structure:

[image: folder_structure]

I am trying to create a list of training images and a list of their corresponding segmentation mask which lives in the `"train"` folder which looks like this:

[image: train_folder]

Each input image has several masks for each person in the image, and for my purposes I'm only interested in the first one. For instance, image `"1.jpg"` has the following masks: `"1_02_01.png"` and `"1_02_02.png"`, but I'm only interested in the first one i.e. `"1_02_01.png"`.

Now when I try to create the lists I've mentioned before using the following code:

[image: code_snippet1]

It produces the following output:

[image: code_snippet2]

Which is totally different than what the original file is structured and how the image pairs should be matched which looks like this:
training images:

[image: imgs]

Their corresponding masks:

[image: masks]

What I want to achieve is to have an `img_list` which stores the images in order e.g. `["1.jpg", "4.jpg", ...]` and their corresponding masks in another list e.g. `["1_02_01.png", "4_02_01.png", ...]` or any other way that could match each image to its corresponding first mask, doesn't necessarily have to be in the order that they are shown in the file explorer.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The results you show for `mask_list` do not match what a `glob.glob('…/*_01.png')` call would return. All those images you have in your question are not really helpful. It would be better to show the actual two lists you're getting from the two `glob.glob`s along with what you would like the resulting list to look like. Please don't post images of the them!

Comment: Yes indeed it was from a previous run where i omitted the _01 from the file path. Sorry for the poor formatting, I'm still learning the correct way to format code in LaTex

Comment: You don't need LaTex to format Python code, just a good editor that makes it easy to follow the [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) guidelines. Note the [naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) it recommends, too, as they are fairly important and only require that you know and follow them when naming things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pathnames are sorted as strings. This can be confusing with numbers because 11 is sorted before 2. This is because the 1 *character* sorts before the 2 *character* in Unicode/ASCII. If we replace 1 and 2 with a and b, respectively, we would expect aa to be sorted before b.

That said, the `sort` function accepts a lambda that allows you to influence the sort order of your list. For example:

```
list = ["2", "11", "3", "1"]
list.sort() #=> ["1", "11", "2", "3"]
list.sort(key=lambda n: int(n)) #=> ["1", "2", "3", "11"]
```

Notice how the lambda doesn't transform the result. It transforms the value for purposes of sorting. The values remain strings.

Comment: What the OP wants to do is more involved than simply sorting the files names a certain way (despite what the question's title says).

Comment: @martineau it was the "key" to what I wanted to achieve, pun intended.